Old video games unexpected behavior
I assume this is a Windows issue hence why I'm posting here and not in a seperate video game site. So, the game (same issue happens to a dozen of older pre 2005) opens normally but then after 5 seconds it minimizes but continues running. I can click on its icon again and it would open normally and then close the window again after 5 seconds but it keeps running, doesn't crash.
What I tried:

Running compatibility mode for Windows XP SP3

Disabling full screen optimizations

Changing high dpi settings


This problem occurred in: Need for Speed: Hot Pursuit 2, Santa Claus in trouble, Rosso Rabbit in trouble, Bus Driver by SCS.
In Bus Driver, the problem went away after I went into settings and changed resolution to fullhd, but other games (like Santa Claus in trouble) don't have any resolution settings so I assume this is a display issue just don't know how to solve it yet.
Edit: I made Santa Claus in trouble and Rosso Rabbit in trouble to work by modifying config files (Resolution changed to fullhd, fullscreen changed from 1 to 0, bit depth changed from 16 to 32) but Need for Speed Hot Pursuit 2 still has some issues. It doesn't launch properly and I can't find its config file.

You'll need to just find solutions for each game. There's no proper global fix for every engine and way the game was coded and designed, as e.g. scaled textures in certain games might look horrid on modern screens. https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=Need+for+Speed+Hot+Pursuit+2+resolution etc.
